# Fusion 2 id columns in a single SELECT request

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostGreSQL, I have a table like this:

```
id | id_tab1 | id_tab2
 1 |     1   |   2
 2 |     1   |   3
 3 |     1   |   4
 4 |     2   |   3
 5 |     3   |   5
 6 |     5   |   7
```

I'd like to get all the integers in a SELECT request from id_tab1 AND id_tab2 without having them repeated. That is to say in my example: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7 (the "6" is not in any column).

I looked towards "INTERSECT", "EXCEPT", up to no avail...
Any clue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Hint: `UNION`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UNION`. Without the `ALL` option it eliminates duplicates in the result.

```
SELECT id_tab1
       FROM elbat
UNION
SELECT id_tab2
       FROM elbat;
```

Your problem *may* however indicate, that you have a design flaw and the table should really be two tables or the two columns should be only one from the start.

Comment: Thanks, I was really stupid as I wrote "UNION ALL", and that gave me doubles... Thank you for your reactivity.

Comment: And the table structure is correct, it's a table a links between 2 other tables, so I have to get both ids in 2 different columns.